# What is the sample size in the AM_MEDIA_TYPE?

Tags: c++, directshow

The AM_MEDIA_TYPE struct looks as following:

```
typedef struct _MediaType {
  GUID     majortype;
  GUID     subtype;
  BOOL     bFixedSizeSamples;
  BOOL     bTemporalCompression;
  ULONG    lSampleSize;
  GUID     formattype;
  IUnknown *pUnk;
  ULONG    cbFormat;
  BYTE     *pbFormat;
} AM_MEDIA_TYPE;
```

Documentation says :

lSampleSize

```
Size of the sample in bytes. For compressed data, the value can be zero.
```

What sample is meant?

Comment: Ok but I have to create a AM_MEDIA_TYPE structure for the connected pin to determine if the connection is accepted. At this stage there exist no samples

Answer (score 2):

`lSampleSize` is basically informational and is an informational size of atomic media stream data block size: video frame size for uncompressed video, minimal audio block size, either per one audio sample or non-divisible frame of data. As an informational value, it is typically ignored.

Answer (score 0):

> What sample is meant?

Sample is basically the **[media sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373477%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** they are referring to.

**Remarks**:

> When two pins connect, they negotiate a media type, which is defined
>   by an AM_MEDIA_TYPE structure. The media type describes the format of
>   the data that the filters will exchange. If the filters do not agree
>   on a media type, they cannot connect.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, where your filter outputs some video, this is the size of video data in one frame. For NV12 it is width * height * 3/2.